# __builtin_return_address won't take a variable as argument

Tags: c++, g++

This is perplexing. Using g++ 4.9.1:

```
int main()
{
    void* r1 = __builtin_return_address(0); // fine
    unsigned int foo = 0;
    void* r2 = __builtin_return_address(foo); // does not compile
 }
```

The error returned is `error: invalid argument to ‘__builtin_return_address’`

The documentation says that this function takes an unsigned int. I know the __builtin functions have all kinds of weirdness, and this just might be how life is, but I need to be able to step through this thing with an incrementing variable for a stack dumper I'm trying to implement. If it only accepts constant arguments, that's not really possible.

Is there a workaround or a better way?

Comment: To implement a stack dumper you may want to use some platform-specific library function - besides the convenience (compared to a gigantic switch) `__builtin_return_address` may not be able to pass through foreign stack frames (think callbacks that pass through function calls that follow another calling convention - classic case: the Win32 event loop). You may want to lookup `backtrace` on Linux and `RtlCaptureStackBacktrace` on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working in a linux environment and the backtrace facility doesn't provide quite everything I need. libunwind does, except this piece. I'd prefer not to have to use both methods and intertwine/merge their outputs, which is why I was hoping for this call to work.

Comment: Exactly what is `backtrace` missing? Some stack frames? Or you need extra functionality? Because `__builtin_return_address`, at least in my experience on x86 - is *very* simplistic (it just goes on dereferencing the saved ebp until the specified depth, and then takes the next address).

Comment: The name of the function, the offset, etc. In other words, all the info I need to get back to a line number in the code. I know `backtrace_symbols` has that stuff but I don't want to have to parse that string in its goofy format.

Comment: Well, if you are ok with libunwind why don't you use its facilities even for the backtrace?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the stack frame return addresses from libunwind.

Comment: See the example at the end of the "Local unwinding" section http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/libunwind(3).html

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own huge switch/case or if/else tree up to as many levels as you may need. You can use macros to make it simpler.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/Dl3Yfb jeez it does generate quite some ugly code